# How to split a slice into a header array reference and a tail slice?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

I'm looking for a function with a signature similar to:

```
split_header_and_tail(buf: &[u8]) -> Option<(&[u8; HEADER_LENGTH], &[u8])>
```

If the supplied slice is too short, the result is `None`, but if it's long enough a reference to the first `HEADER_LENGTH` bytes and the tail slice are returned.

The first part must be a reference to a fixed-length array, as I need to subdivide it into various fixed-length fields.

Comment: Nitpick: `&[T]` is not a vector but a _slice_.

Comment: I'm calling it with a reference to a vector, but you are correct, these are slices.  I have corrected the question title.  Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On nightly, there is [`split_array_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_array_ref):

```rust
#![feature(split_array)]

fn split_header_and_tail(buf: &[u8]) -> Option<(&[u8; HEADER_LENGTH], &[u8])> {
    if buf.len() < HEADER_LENGTH {
        None
    } else {
        Some(buf.split_array_ref())
    }
}
```

On stable, you can use `TryInto`:

```rust
fn split_header_and_tail(buf: &[u8]) -> Option<(&[u8; HEADER_LENGTH], &[u8])> {
    if buf.len() < HEADER_LENGTH {
        None
    } else {
        let (head, tail) = buf.split_at(HEADER_LENGTH);
        Some((head.try_into().unwrap(), tail))
    }
}
```